# C# string array getting only the first 10 values

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array that has a list of values like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

I am trying only to get the first ten so my output looks like this and store it another string array.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

it seems really easy i just can't figure it out

Comment: Are you trying to get a sub-array that contains only the first 10 objects or trying to read the first 10 objects ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<Math.Min(10, array.Length); i++)
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
```

OR

```
foreach (int i in array.Take(10))        
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
```

EDIT: Based on your comment that you want it in a string array. Here is what you have to do

```
string[] numbers = array.Take(10).Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is it possible to store it in another string array

Comment: Yes: var newArray = array.Take(10).ToArray();

Comment: And even better: `var newList = array.Take(10).ToList();`

Answer (score 15):

You can use Linq. You need to include the reference and the using directive:

```
using System.Linq;

theStringsArray.Take(10).ToArray();
```

Comment: I like your style

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`Array.Copy(SourceArray, DestinationArray, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually decided you did not care about the source array after all, you could simply resize it in order to get rid of the unwanted values:

```
Array.Resize(ref myArray, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArraySegment to do this without creating intermediate lists or enumerators:

```
using System;

string[] newArray = (new ArraySegment<string>(oldArray, 0, 10)).ToArray();
```

This can also be used to take any part of the array.